# IOS video file to play automatically when application startup

Tags: ios, file, video

How to play video automatically without having to press the play button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"yourVideoPath"]];
player.shouldAutoplay=YES;
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 320.0);
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;    
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

[self.view  addSubview:player.view];
```

this should solve your problem. Tried and tested

Comment: This allows me to play but does not play automatically. Is it possible to just open the application and the video starts playing without having to press the play button?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on MPMoviePlayerController?  Everything you need to know is in there.

Comment: But let's share with others: you need to add [player.moviePlayer play].